# authenfication into googleAnalytics using R

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I  apply `googleAnalyticsR` to use the Google-API. I create a project ans want to log in:

```
library(googleAnalyticsR)
library(googleAuthR)
ga_auth(email="username@gmail.com")
```

after login via browser I get the following message in browser

```
Authentication complete. Please close this page and return to R.
```

however, in Rstudio I get the following error:

```
Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
Authentication complete.
Eror: Could not authenticate via any gargle cred function
```

could it be that the problem lies on the firewall? If true, which adress should be activated in order get the authentification working? `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics`?

Comment: If you use options(googleAuthR.verbose=2) and rerun the auth, do you get some more logging debugging info?

Comment: I did it and get : gar_token_info(detail_level = getOption("googleAuthR.verbose", default = 2))
No token found
NULL

Comment: Weird, try it with just `ga_auth()` (no arguments) but otherwise maybe try it on https://rstudio.cloud/project/1125233 to see if its something to do with your local setup